# Believing in Humans but Not in Reality

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-logic

I find it odd that some in the philosophic world won't commit to admitting reality is a reality, however 
they will wholeheartedly believe 
in a human who declares reality an impossibility.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hello and welcome to philosophy.se! Do you think you can provide some specific examples of philosophers who have argued this? The more specific you can get about this question the better the answers you will get are going to be because they'll be honed in on specific argues as opposed to just a general statement about these ideas.

Comment: Nobody has ever refused to admit that Reality is Reality. I know what you're getting at but you haven't said it. Philosophers often conclude that Existence is not what we usually think it is and that Reality outreaches Existence, but everybody agrees that whatever it is Reality is Reality.

Comment: How would any philosopher refuse to admit that x=x? That would mean accepting true=false. Logic (the universe-governing rules) and reasoning (its mental application) are the pure essence of philosophy. Your question does not fit as a philosophical one, and not even a logical one.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may seem contradictory, there are ways to make this make sense.  For instance, suppose, unknown to you, you had been hooked into a virtual reality simulation that exactly duplicates the world as you now know it.  While in that simulated world, you interact (virtually) with other human beings who are also real beings hooked into the same simulation.  In that case, if one of them declared "this is all a fake," she could be a real person in a fake world.

Classically speaking, both Plato and Descartes, as well as many other idealists, believed that the mind is more real than the body.  If we think of a human being primarily as their mind, then it is possible the human (the mind) is real in a fake world, for instance, when dreaming.  Of course, two minds don't generally share the same dream, but if you were the dream character, being addressed by (for example) a lucid dreamer, then a real person could be telling you real information about a fake world.

It could also be that the person is not real, but the idea is.  In the same scenario, except reversed, you might be the real person dreaming, and the dream character, although unreal, is telling you real information about the fake world you seem to be inhabiting.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a language problem with the word "believe", I think.  Do you mean believe in what such a human says, or do you mean believe that such a human is real?  Because I could believe in what such a human says, without committing myself to believe that he is real. Couldn't I?  By playing with the word believe in this way, I think you also beg the question, but I will leave such a determination to the fallacy and logic experts here.

Answer (score 0):

Reality is not dependent upon a definition – it is what it is. As everything changes from a state of “now” to the next state of “now”, it does so at the smallest increments of energy possible (entropy), and at the maximum speed possibly, which of course, limits the speed of light.  Absolute realty is the time in between the beginning “now” and the ending “now”.  What this particular beginning and end set looks like is a different question for another day.

Humans occupy a biological body form for a temporary period during this time set; so, they are therefore a part of reality. The brain, being a part of the body, and the housing for a network of temporally synapsed neurons is also part of reality. From these particular neuron networks, an illusionary (and coherent for most humans) consciousness or perception of “self” (mind) develops from inputs of an elaborate set of sensing neurons. The mind’s existence (and its thought patterns) are also part of reality because their entire essence is sourced from biological activity.

Comment: Glenn- I feel this is unrigorous. You do not know.. "The mind’s existence (and its thought patterns) are also part of reality because their entire essence is sourced from biological activity." It is a theory and hotly contested.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that just because someone takes part in philosophy, does not mean the axioms they use to form their beliefs are always logically sound.

I would argue that the field of philosophy draws a lot of curious people who are prone to accept a lot of philosophical thought on authority, or even just because they like the idea, and not necessarily because of some bulletproof rationalization.

And so the result is that it's not uncommon for some people who practice philosophy to make claims that are actually unsound.